# Charles proxy ssl inspection fails for the requests that originates from Android app but not the browser

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I configured charles proxy I am able to intercept SSL traffic originating from browser of the android phone and I am not facing any issue

But https request originating from android mobile app failing with SSL trust error

this is weird

Update:

Charles root certificate is not trusted by application while its trusted by browsers..weird

Comment: The might have implemented SSL Certificate Pinning to stop Man in the Middle attacks

Comment: I tired with some sample app which is not implemented SSL pining but the same issue happens